Meaning of はっきりせんかい
I've encountered this in multiple places:

A game script I'm translating has a psychic exclaim "はっきりせんかい！" right before having a vision of the protagonist's future.

A tweet "暖かいのか寒いのかハッキリせんかい"

Title of this blogpost


I'm assuming はっきり is "clearly" in these cases, but what is せんかい supposed to be?

～ん is an alternative negative form to ～ない, derived from the old ～ぬ form. する became せぬ with that negative, so せん roughly equals しない. In fiction it's often associated with older, strong-willed speakers. ～ないか in general, with the right intonation, can be used to make a kind of forceful demand. せんかい is along the same lines.
はっきりせんかい therefore means something like 'Be clear about it, will you?!'

There's an English phrasing that might more closely parallel the Japanese, and that is often delivered as a kind of exasperated exclamation, even as the word order suggests a question (much like the かい in the Japanese would usually suggest a question): "Won't you be clear about it!"

@EiríkrÚtlendi - It's supposed to be a つっこみ in Kansai-ben although most Kansai-ben speakers would say 暖かいんか寒いんか.

An idiomatic English equivalent would be "Make up your damn mind!"
